# large value in drop down not able to see in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five</option>
  <option value="saab">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

I am creating dynamicaly dropdown. In that user can create wih 200/option  charactor.
eg.

```
 <select class="my_dropdown" id="my_dropdown">
    <option value="1"> value is upto 200 charactor.............200</option>
    <option value="2">value is upto 200 charactor..............200 charactor</option>
  </select>
```

In browser only show uptu 100 charactor. Rest is going outside the browser which is not able to see.
If drop down is on right on browser then not able to see more then around 40 charactors.
how to show complete 200 charactor in browser.

Comment: You should add the CSS related to your question to. Preferably put your html, css to the [jsbin](https://jsbin.com) to demo your problem. Your problem might be not having appropriate styling.

Answer (score 0):

You can't wrap text of a native `select` element, you will need some javascript component like `JQueryUI`. See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/8489/) for example.

Enhanced dropdown with JQueryUI: https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/

Comment: what is selectmenu() function is there.

Comment: @Bachas `selectmenu` is a JQueryUI method that turns your original `select` into an enhanced JQueryUI dropdown. With that new dropdown you can apply lots of custom CSS rules since it converts your `option` tag into `span`.

Comment: @ Nicolas Cami code is running fine .will you give me the current version of these blow js and css file

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: @Bachas What's your request exactly?